# Is there a computing process heavily dependent on the principles of gravity?

Tags: gravity, computer

Most of the current and future computing technology depends on the application of physics of subatomic entities (electrodynamics and quantum mechanics). Since we haven't explored the gravitational frontier (to the best of my knowledge), wouldn't it be exciting to explore gravitational phenomena to get better systems for computing. Is there any research done in this area?

Comment: Yeah, at my university there was an old computer made of wood that relied on balls rolling down slopes. Does that count?

Comment: We had the same one, but ours made toast as well! Did yours!?

Comment: Stonehenge and the predictions of solstices relies heavily on gravitation keeping the Earth orbiting the sun?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There is no way to turn pulses of gravity on and off, and it cannot be sent through wires or pipes to carry information, or stored for later retrieval.

Comment: Is there a reason to believe that a gravitational wave waveguide isn't possible in principle?

Comment: @d_b, yes. they are not electromagnetic.

Comment: Surely you don't mean to claim that only EM waves can be guided, do you? You must be aware that there are also acoustic waveguides, for example, and that we could impose similar boundary conditions (perhaps just in principle) on other kinds of waves.

Comment: acoustic "waveguides" do not work like EM waveguides. the physics is completely different. furthermore, gravity waves are waves in the fabric of space which means that the waveguide just gets rippled and cannot focus or contain them.